# Openshift application stopped and restarted automaticlally with catridge of type DIY

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, cloud, openshift, openshift-cartridge

Opens shift application stopped  and restarted automatically  with cartridge of type DIY,so continues downtime for my application,as i running spring boot application with PostgreSQL database and the server starts and can see application running but after while server is down why and then it automatically started and automatically shutdown ,i also see only few logs in logs directory  following are the logs

```
these are some logs for application---->
```

rhc tail tiworld

```
==> app-root/logs/diy.log <==
[2016-07-22 08:55:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-07-22 08:55:41] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-07-22 08:55:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=380495 port=8080
127.3.82.129 - - [22/Jul/2016:09:10:32 EDT] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
127.3.82.129 - - [22/Jul/2016:09:10:32 EDT] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
[2016-07-22 09:21:58] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2016-07-22 09:21:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.


==> app-root/logs/postgresql.log <==
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2016-07-27 12:45:45 GMT
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT LOG:  record with zero length at 0/198F218
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT LOG:  redo is not required
2016-07-27 12:51:12 GMT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
You can tail this application directly with:
ssh -t 579217552d5271eaa80000c0@programmers-pvb.rhcloud.com 'tail */log*/*'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:30:in `select': closed stream (IOError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:30:in `io_select'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:75:in `available_for_read?'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:87:in `next_packet'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:183:in `block in poll_message'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `poll_message'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:461:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `preprocess'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:206:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `block in loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:198:in `block in ssh_ruby'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:173:in `ssh_ruby'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/tail.rb:40:in `tail'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/tail.rb:21:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/runner.rb:421:in `run_active_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/delegates.rb:8:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a small gear *especially if you have java & a db on the same gear*, changes are that you are running out of resources and the gear is restarting (after awhile it will not restart automatically anymore).
You can check out this article for more information on checking your memory utilization: https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues

Comment: yes i am out of resourcess, so how can  i put postgress on different gear and access it with small gear,i cant upgrade my plan,i have to do it with small gear how can i? help

Comment: you would need to create it as a scaled application (as long as you have enough gears left) and it will automatically put the database on it's own gear.

Comment: i am using free trial and i have 3 gears can i scale these three gears,if how please give me the best resourse

Comment: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/scaling.html

Comment: Most of the standard OpenShift web cartridges are scalable using HAProxy, with the exception of the Do-It-Yourself, Jenkins, and Zend cartridges.

Comment: i M USING diy cartridge

Comment: The DIY cartridge is not scalable.

Comment: so what i have to do now